# Website Meta Not Pulling Through to Facebook, Twitter or Linkedin

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, metadata, meta-tags

I have been having some issues with metatags on my website. Open graph validators all recognise that I have meta data available on each page however neither facebook, twitter or linkedin seem able to pick it up.

Twitter specifically says: WARN:  No metatags found

I recently changed all of our web page names from:
www.website.com/blogs.html to 
www.website.com/blogs 
and since then it seems that twitter etc are no longer whitelisted (the reason I say that is because the twitter card validator no longer gives me the green box that says it is whitelisted).

Here is an example of one of the pages that isn't working:
http://cuttsyandcuttsy.com/blogs/Mar-2018/its-more-than-just-a-font

I should probably point out that there is also a .htaccess file sat on the website redirecting people from the old blog posts to the new versions of them (website redesigned).

I have no idea why it's not picking it up or how to fix it but any help on the matter would be appreciated.

I can also provide the code if you need it.

Comment: Fb debug tool shows a few warnings, but seems to read most of the data fine ... so what is the actual issue here?

Comment: @CBroe try using the Twitter validator instead: https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: @CBroe Basically twitter and facebook don't seem to be pulling the images in the meta through.

Comment: Facebook debug tool shows the image fine.